# Cannot see unsung hero badge in "Select your next badge" list

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, badge-progress, zero-score-badges

I was checking what kind of Badges are available and what's their requirements, when I noticed some user profiles have the "unsung hero" gold badge which I cannot see in the Gold Badge from my user profile. I'm not talking about earning the badge, I know the requirement, just curious to why not on the list? and are there other badges as well which are hidden for some reason?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the trackable badges?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft .. I think so

Comment: Who's profile did you see it on?

Comment: @ʇolɐǝzǝɥʇqoq we can see this only on our own profiles, when clicking "choose which badge to track". (It's part of the new profile design)

Comment: For instance, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1881196/dlask) user

Comment: @IronFist that's totally not relevant. Of course people get the badge. The issue here is why the badge does not appear in the list to track.

Comment: @ShadowWizard .. yea...just to reply to a comment

Comment: Knew it was asked before, dupe wasn't tagged properly (missing [tag:profile-page] tag) so it was hard to find.

Comment: I posted [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272452/245360) to overcome this issue. It might be interesting to you.