# Gray out untrackable badges in 'Select your next badge' dialog

Tags: feature-request, badges, design, profile-page

Sometimes we get questions on why a specific badge can't be tracked from the 'Select your next badge' dialog, [like this one about the Unsung Hero badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272449/245360).

[The answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263610/245360) seems to be that they have a high impact on the performance, so they are not shown.

I suggest to show the badges in the dialog, but gray them out so they can't be selected (and show a reason why next to it). This way, users understand why they can't track the badge and we don't confuse users any more.

Comment: We can also disable tracking forever.

Comment: And how is that helpful?

Comment: On second thought, there are too many badges, having them all in there will clutter the design. Maybe just show the gold or something?

Comment: At least if you search for one, it should show. @sha

Comment: This is kind of counter-intuitive, I won't expect to see a badge that doesn't exist in the "All" tab for example. Still agree with your request, just sharing my concerns about it.

Comment: At least put in a link telling 'why can't I see all badges?' or so

Comment: This is slightly different than your request, but the confusing ones for me are the tag badges where I may have substantial progress on score/answers, but I can't track the tag badge.  Reason is because the tag doesn't have 100 questions yet and is ineligible for tag badges.